# Finding the min and max of a test

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This program just prints out the Fibonacci numbers and how long it took them to be calculated using two different methods. I need to be able to find the max and the min of how long it took them to be calculated for each number after I repeat the time test 6 times. I know how to repeat it six times I just can't figure out how to find the min and the max out of those 6 tests. What I think I need it to is add a loop right before the GetTickCount() functions and then have if statements to compare the test each time it goes through. Is that correct or am I thinking wrong? And if it is correct how exactly is it done? I've tried it a few different ways but it ends up printing the same numbers for every single Fibonacci number.

ex.

0  min = 0 max = 155

1  min = 0 max = 155

1  min = 0 max = 155

2  min = 0 max = 155

3  min = 0 max = 155

5  min = 0 max = 155

8  min = 0 max = 155

```
const int MAXN(45);

int main()
{
  unsigned long int before, after, diff, result;

  cout << "Execution time for Fibonacci no. implementions (ms)\n";
  cout << setfill('+') << setw(64) << "+" << endl << setfill(' ');
  cout << setw(4) << "n" << setw(30) << "Recursive"
  << setw(30) << "Iterative" << endl;
  cout << setfill('+') << setw(64) << "+" << endl << setfill(' ');
  for (int n=0; n<=MAXN; n++) {
    cout << setw(4) << n;

    before=GetTickCount();
    result=FiboRecursive(n);
    after=GetTickCount();

    diff=after-before;
    cout << setw(20) << result << setw(10) << diff;

    before=GetTickCount();
    result=FiboIterative(n);
    after=GetTickCount();

    diff=after-before;
    cout << setw(20) << result << setw(10) << diff;
    cout << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `GetTickCount` is a supremely poor timer to use for this. Use `chrono::high_resolution_clock` instead

Comment: @MikeVine I understand it is but my teacher said we had to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to loop over the number of samples you want to test, and check the results.

Using `chrono::high_resolution_clock` as suggested in comments:

```
...

for (int n=0; n<=MAXN; n++) {

    double min = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
    double max = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        result=FiboRecursive(n);
        auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        double duration = (end - start).count();
        min = std::min(min, duration);
        max = std::max(max, duration);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Using GetTickCount():

```
for (int n=0; n<=MAXN; n++) {

    unsigned long int min = std::numeric_limits<unsigned long int >::max();
    unsigned long int max = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        unsigned long int start = GetTickCount();
        result=FiboRecursive(n);
        unsigned long int end = GetTickCount();
        double duration = end - start;
        min = std::min(min, duration);
        max = std::max(max, duration);
    }

    std::cout << "For n: " << n << ", min: " << min << ", max: " << max;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was not able to use it though because I have to use the GetCountTik() for this class. I just ended up setting up an array and put the values in there and then found the min and max of that array.

Comment: If you have to use GetTickCount(), the same thing applies, you just need to change the units.  I'll update the answer.